# dplyr cannot work in group by month

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to do the group by month and year but the results show "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'MM' not found". Does anyone can help this? thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
uq_app %>% 
select(Date, sales, convs) %>%
mutate(MM= format(Date, "%m"), YY= format(Date, "%Y")) %>%
group_by(MM, YY) %>%
summarise(total_conv = sum(convs))

Date           sl convs fi op  cl
03/10/2015      0   0    0  0   0
03/10/2015      0   0   36  13  7
03/10/2015      0   0   13  6   1
03/10/2015      0   0   17  6   1
03/10/2015      0   0   1   1   0
03/10/2015      0   0   30  19  5
03/10/2015  272.6   2   13  3   2
04/10/2015      0   0   0   0   0
04/10/2015  512.2   6   56  27  7
04/10/2015  112.4   2   21  8   1
04/10/2015  142.2   1   24  11  0
04/10/2015      0   0   4   0   0
04/10/2015   60.4   1   25  11  0
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Inside the `%>%`, you don't need `uq_app$` , just `format(Date, "%m")` is enough

Comment: @akrun, I remove that but still show the same error.

Comment: @ Aramis7d, sorry accidentally delete your comment. It still now work. my date format is "Date"

Comment: My original comment would be relevant if it still doesn' work.  i.e. show a small reproducible example

Comment: @ akrun, please see an example, thanks

Comment: I understand the problem, you didn't convert to `Date` class.

Comment: @ChrisChang you should probably look into `str()` to verify types of the columns, and decide on a suitable format.

Answer (score 2):

We need to convert to `Date` class before extracting the 'month' and 'year'

```
uq_app %>% 
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
    group_by(MM = format(Date, '%m'), YY = format(Date, '%Y')) %>% 
    summarise(total_conv = sum(convs))
#    MM    YY total_conv
#  <chr> <chr>      <int>
#1    03  2015          2
#2    04  2015         10
```